# What is (or was) http://cycling-exchange.com/ ?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled across http://cycling-exchange.com/ when looking at Area51. It looks inactive now, but what was it and how does it relate to this site ?  Does anyone know why it failed to pick up or died off - it would be good to know so this site avoids similar fate.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. Perhaps it's an old StackExchange 1.0 site. Perhaps you cross-post this on [SE meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [list of registered users](http://cycling-exchange.com/users), it becomes painfully clear why it didn't pick up.

Not enough promotion ⇒ no users ⇒ no participation.

Area51 is different in that it ensures that every new site has a certain amount of momentum right from day one, or else it won't get created to begin with. Jeff and Joel have stated many times that they do not want to, and will not, create "ghost towns".

> We do not believe that the Internet benefits from putting up placeholder sites with negligible traffic that do not attract high quality communities.

Taken from [this entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) on the StackOverflow blog. Read it for further insight.

Answer (score 4):

It was a SE beta site.

Site was mine. I just didn't have the funds nor time dedication to promote it like it needed. The domain still works, but cycling.stackexchange.com now redirects to bicycling.stackexchange.com, so just a matter of time before it gets turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely part of the original StackExchange beta.  There used to be a listing on StackExchange.com but I can't seem to find it now.  I remember there were quite a few topical sites, but many of them fizzled due to lack of users.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016, the domain is now owned by a domain squatter.

Our good friend the Way Back Machine has the page archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20100511061702/http://cycling-exchange.com/  You can click though this link and read some of the questions/answers.  Some haven't really changed.

In case archive.org ever goes away, here's a shot of the page as it was on January 31 2011.
[image]

Observations:

- Meta was just a tag back then, as shown by question about login issues
- Product recommendations were more acceptable.
- The basic concept and design is unchanged, with answers, votes and tags, and bounties and badges.